# Back Linear Substitution

Tags: matrix, replacement

I have an equation set `Ax=b` and `A(n*m),n<m` . To lower down the dimension, I express some vars by other vars, which gives `By=c`. After some calculation, the values of `y` is achieved and I want to get `x` back. How can I accomplish this work?

**The main aim is to get the substitution and back substitution, instead of solving the equations.**

Remark: `n` and `m` are not fixed, the code need to be general for different scales.

For example:

```
x[1]+x[2]+x[3]==1&&x[2]+x[4]==1
```

Then we have:

```
x[1]==x[4]-x[3]&&x[2]==1-x[4]
```

And after some calculation, I get `{x[3],x[4]}=={0,1}` and I want to get:

```
{x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4]}=={1,0,0,1}
```

I know it's silly to use `x[i]`, as I can't handle matrices well. I believe there is a way to finish all these in the language of matrices.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more please?  First, there are syntax errors/ambiguities (using [] when I think you mean [[]], and = when you mean ==) and your example looks like a system of two equations with four unknowns.

Comment: @bobthechemist actually,x[i] can be used as variables, you can think of this as x_i, but x_i means something else in MMA. Here I'm not trying to solve the equations, I'd like to have a method to do the substitution and back substitution. And a method using pure matrices instead of a lot of x[i] would be better.

Comment: [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) seems to be what you're after.  Or perhaps [`LinearSolve[A, b]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html) plus [`NullSpace[A]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NullSpace.html)

Comment: `ReplaceAll` with a certain set of rules comes to mind ...

Comment: As $n<m$, $\boldsymbol{\mathrm A}\cdot \boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{b}$ is an underdetermined system, `Solve` should have no problem to [handle it](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html#308488225).